# Encog getError() returns Infinity

Tags: neural-network, encog

I built following neural network with help of Encog library for Java

```
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(DataCooker.DATA_SIZE));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(DataCooker.DATA_SIZE));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(DataCooker.DATA_SIZE));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(DataCooker.DATA_SIZE));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(1));
network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
network.reset();
```

Also, I prepared test-data and tried to train this NN with help of this train

```
Train train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);
```

But, i found that on some data case (rare) I am receiving train.getError() equals to Infinity (not depends how many epochs passed).
Data looks good from first glance (all are numbers, no NaN, no Infinity values).

What is possible reasons for this Infinity error? What can I do to solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sorry, data was bad indeed, output for bad cases was Infinity